# Outlook 2016 Way to set rules to run on a subfolder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, rules, folder-redirection

I have a rules set up that move emails with a certain criteria from the inbox into a sud-folder called "Evening"  is it then possible to set a rule that moves email from the folder "Evening" folder into other sub-folders for specific people i.e "person A" folder or "person b" folder.

I cannot do it from the main inbox as doing so would require over 160 different rules.  doing it this way would only require 45 rules in total

Answer (score 1):

To set up a rule on a subfolder,
Open an email **that exists in that subfolder** and then select Create Rule. At the end you will see the option: "Run rule on folder 'xxx'"
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to set rules for folders other than inbox. Because the full name of the Rule is Inbox Rules. [Use inbox rules in Outlook.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-inbox-rules-in-outlook-com-4b094371-a5d7-49bd-8b1b-4e4896a7cc5d)